AWS Redshift SQL - How to check if a Json object has values in it?
1/ I am using SQL on AWS and trying to detect quickly when a Json object has key-value in it. Anyone knows it? Thanks
For example:
A. {"context":{"abc":"123"} --> Yes
B. {"context":{}} --> No
Note that I don't know in advance the keys in this case.
2/ Also is it possible to collect all the keys?
Thank you.

Tagging which DBMS engine would be a good start

I assume you are using AWS Athena, you can use json_extract to parse the json string and then use json_length to check if the json object number of keys is more than 0
SELECT
  dataset.name, dataset.data
FROM (
  SELECT 'A' AS name, '{"context":{"abc":"123"}}' AS data
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'B' , '{"context":{}}'
) as dataset
where json_length(json_extract(dataset.data, '$.context')) > 0


Hi, thanks for your answer. I use Amazon Redshift actually. Do you know if it is possible?

I edited my question to include Redshift info, and another question - if it's possible to collect all the keys. Thanks

In Redshift the easiest way to work with json data is as a super data type column.  You can do this as json text but it isn't as powerful.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html
There are a number of ways to do what you want.  Here's a couple:
with foo as (
  SELECT 'A' AS name, json_parse('{"context":{"abc":"123"}}') AS data
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'B' , json_parse('{"context":{}}')
)
select name, data.context, json_size(data.context), data.context.abc
from foo;

As for your #2 objective this can be done by unpivoting the object in the super you want to get the keys for.  Like this:
with foo as (
  SELECT 'A' AS name, json_parse('{"context":{"abc":"123", "def":"456"}}') AS data
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'B' , json_parse('{"context":{}}')
)
select name, data.context, key
from foo as f, unpivot f.data.context as value at key;


For #2, the query throws an error on the last line, without specific reason.
It highlights "f.data.context" though I'm not sure if it's the hint

Actually #1 didn't work either. Sorry it was running earlier and I thought the query would pass. Looks like json_parse didn't work. The query results in an error around "."

These are self contained queries that were run successfully on Redshift.  Did you run them as is or adapt them for your data?  If the latter, can you provide more details on what exactly was run?   json_parse() not working is a clue that the text given isn't valid json - it is picky.

Assuming your object always follows the structure {context:{}}, you could use the following:
SELECT json_object_keys(my_field::json->'context') AS a FROM my_table

Where my_field is the field in your table my_table which contains the JSON objects. This will return a table where the rows are the keys of the JSON inside context.
You can find more information here.
Note that this is PostgreSQL, I know Redshift uses a subset of this, but hopefully this helps.
